# Background process gets killed in ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, process, kill, webserver

I have a spring boot application and i'm running it as **ROOT** through this command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m" > lms_logs.log 2>&1 &
```

After a few hours it shutsdown with these logs statements:

```
011 11-01-2019 03:50:00.010 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.app.jobs.ScheduledJobsConfiguration.uploadScoreReports - Started uploadScoreReports job...
011 11-01-2019 03:50:37.701 [Thread-3] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@3a85bcaa: startup date [Fri Jan 11 03:27:13 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy
011 11-01-2019 03:50:37.704 [Thread-3] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter.destroy - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
011 11-01-2019 03:50:37.705 [Thread-3] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter.unregisterBeans - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
011 11-01-2019 03:50:37.718 [Thread-3] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.destroy - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
011 11-01-2019 03:50:37.719 [Thread-3] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
011 11-01-2019 03:50:37.731 [Thread-3] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.close - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-01-11T03:50:37+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 76M/451M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why could this happen ?

Comment: I believe `ApplicationContext.doClose` indicates a controlled shutdown. Can you check if this is happening when the user who runs the `mvn` command logs out?

Comment: Sorry, you 'started the user as root'? Can you edit the question and add the details on how you started the program? The problem might be caused by a SIGHUP being sent to the process when the user logs out.

Comment: Apologies for the typo. 
This shouldn't have happened since i started the application as the root user and logged in as a different user.

Something like this: 

ssh ubuntu &
sudo su &
start app &
exit &
exit